# How do I convert a VM from VMWare fusion to ESX?

Tags: vmware-esx, vmware-fusion

I have a buildVM running in Fusion that is in need of some more power so I want to move it to an ESX host.

- What do I need to do to the VM before I move it?
- where on the ESX host should I put it (local storage here)
- what should I do to it after its physically on the ESX host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install VmWare Convertor on it.  Make sure that your vm can ping esx host.
The converter will convert the machine and make it as an esx vm for you.

As for storage...  depends on your enviroment.  Without knowing your specific can't really help you all that much.

As for what you should do.  What do you mean?  Assuming the vm has network connectivity you can do everything you are doing now.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to just copy the vm from the Fucion host to the ESX host.  On the Mac running Fusion each of the VM's appear as one file, but in actuality they are all packages (sort of like a zip archive).  You can easily right-click on any VM package and choose view package contents.  From there all of the files pertaining to that VM is visible in the Finder window.  You should then be able to copy these files to your ESX given that it's running v4 vSphere.  Depending on how you do your storage for the ESX is going to determine how you would go about copying the files.